# A geometric sequence of measurable functions with $|f_n|\leq 1$ on a measure space $(X,\mathcal M, \mu)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a measurable function with $|f|< 1$ on a measure space $(X,\mathcal M, \mu)$, does the limit exist:

$$\lim_n \int 1 + f + f^2 + f^3 + \cdots  + f^n \,d\mu$$

Some consequences up front:

$f^n \in L^1$ for all $n\geq 1$.

If $\sum_0^n f^i(x) = S_n(x)$, then

My conclusions:

For each $x$, $S_n(x) \rightarrow \frac{1}{1-f}$ since $|f(x)|<1$.

If there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $|f|\leq 1-\epsilon$, then $|\frac{1}{1-f}| \leq \epsilon^{-1}$, which, since $\mu(X)<\infty$, means that $|S_n|$ is dominated by an $L^1$ function. Thus $\lim_n \int S_n = \int \lim S_n = \int \frac{1}{1-f} < \infty$.

If on the other hand there does not exist such an $\epsilon$, we have for $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{|f(x)|>1- \epsilon\}$ is of positive measure. If $|f|>1-\epsilon$, then $\int |1 + f + \cdots + f^n| \geq \int_{|f|>1-\epsilon} |\frac{1-f^{n+1}}{1-f}| \geq \int_{|f|>1-\epsilon} \frac{1-|f|^{n+1}}{\epsilon} \rightarrow \mu(|f|>1-\epsilon)\epsilon^{-1}$. But this doesn't help me prove that the limit is infinity. I'm trying to show the limit always exists - even in the infinite case.

Comment: Think of a simple example, $X = (0,1)$, say. And pick a simple $f$ with $0 \leqslant f(x) < 1$ and $\sup \{ f(x) : x \in (0,1)\} = 1$.

Comment: Let $f(x) = x$. Then $\int f^n = 1/(n+1)$, the harmonic series, so that $\int S_n \rightarrow \infty$. I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: That's the example I had in mind. It shows that generally, the limit function is not integrable, and the sequence of integrals unbounded. I missed that you wanted to show that the limit always exists in $[-\infty,+\infty]$, sorry. I think I have the solution, needs a few more minutes of thinking.

Comment: Just to make sure, the functions are real-valued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is real-valued, splitting it into its positive and negative part solves the problem. Let

$$g(x) = \max \{ 0, f(x)\};\quad h(x) = \max \{0, -f(x)\}.$$

Then $f(x) = g(x)-h(x)$, and at each point of $X$, at most one of $g$ and $h$ takes a value $\neq 0$. Then

$$f(x)^n = g(x)^n + (-1)^n h(x)^n,$$

and both $g^n$ and $h^n$ monotonically converge to $0$, so

$$G_n = \int_X g^n\,d\mu \searrow 0;\quad H_n = \int_X h^n\,d\mu \searrow 0.$$

The series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n H_n$$

is (conditionally, probably) convergent by the alternating series criterion. The series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty G_n$$

converges either to a finite limit, or to $+\infty$. Thus

$$\int_X S_n\,d\mu = \sum_{k=0}^n G_k + \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k H_k$$

converges, either to a finite limit, or to $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. In the problem it didn't state about whether this function is complex or real-valued. It's annoying but I guess we can split things up? Or does it not work so smoothly. Can you think of a counterexample?

Comment: I tend to believe it would still hold for complex-valued $f$, but it surely isn't as easy to see then. Gotta think about it.